# Difference between stopping times in deterministic optimal control

Tags: partial-differential-equations, control-theory, stopping-times, optimal-control

I am currently reading the book "Controlled Markov Processes and Viscosity solutions" by Fleming and Soner. In the first chapter about deterministic controls, they introduce a differentiation between stopping times from a closed and an open set.
They consider the cost functional
\begin{align}
    J(t_0,x_0;u)
    =
    \int_{t_0}^{\tau} L(s,x(s), u(s)) ds + g(\tau,x(\tau)) \chi_{\tau < t_1}+ \psi(x(t_1)) \chi_{\tau \geq t_1}
    \label{OptB}
\end{align}
the function $g$ is assumed to be continuous,
and standard control equation\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
     &{x}_t(t)=f(t,x(t),u(t)),\\
    &x(t_0)=x_0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
In order to guarantee the existence of a unique solution, they assume
\begin{align*}
    ||f(t,x,v)-f(t,y,v)|| < L ||x-y|| \quad \text{ for all }t\in[t_0,t_1],x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{align*}

Concretely, they make a distinction between considering the exit from an open set $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ or from its closure $\overline{O}$. Consider first the exit time from $\overline{O}$
\begin{align}
    \tau :=
    \begin{cases}
    \inf \{s \in [t_0,t_1) : x(s) \not \in \overline{O} \}
    \\
    t_1, \text{ if } x(s) \in \overline{O} \text{ for all } s\in [t_0,t_1] 
    \end{cases}
    \label{closed_stop_time}
\end{align}
or alternatively the exit time from the open set $O$
\begin{align}
    \tau :=
    \begin{cases}
    \inf \{s \in [t_0,t_1) : x(s)  \in \partial O \}
    \\
    t_1, \text{ if } x(s) \in O \text{ for all } s\in [t_0,t_1).
    \end{cases}
    \label{open_stop_time}
\end{align}
However, both definitions imply $(\tau , x(\tau)) \in ([t_0,t_1)\times \partial O)\cup (\{t_1 \}\times \overline{O})$ as long as $x$ is assumed to be continuous.
\
I am aware, that the \textit{cost} associated with $x(.)\in \partial O$ depends on the choice of the stopping times. In the case of equation (\eqref{closed_stop_time}) we associate $x(.)\in \partial O$ with the running cost $L$, while in the case of equation (\eqref{open_stop_time}) we associate it with the boundary cost $g$. Although this is useful for understanding the modeling, it remains unclear why such a distinction would be necessary.
\

The distinction also does not seem to have any effect on the proof techniques besides some stricter regularity assumptions regarding the HJB-equations and verification theorems. Why would they make such a distinction? What am I missing?

EDIT: Note that what I referred to as stop or stopping time seems to be called exit time in the area of toptimal control.